# hibernate infinity loop for loading parent in child

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate seems to get into an infinite recursion even though I have no hierarchical mappings set up. 
Basically what I'm trying to do is set up a one-to-many mapping in parent and many-to-one in child class

parent class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "ip")
public class FinalInvolvedParty {
private int ipId;
private List<IPIdentifier> iPIdentifierList;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ip_id", updatable = false)
public Integer getIpId() {
    return ipId;
}

public void setIpId(int ipId) {
    this.ipId = ipId;
}

@OneToMany
@Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "ip_id", nullable = false)
public List<IPIdentifier> getiPIdentifierList() {
    return iPIdentifierList;
}

public void setiPIdentifierList(List<IPIdentifier> iPIdentifierList) {
    this.iPIdentifierList = iPIdentifierList;
}
....
```

and child class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "ip_identifier")
public class IPIdentifier {
private int ipIdentifierId;
private FinalInvolvedParty ipById;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ip_Identifier_Id", updatable = false)
public int getIpIdentifierId() {
    return ipIdentifierId;
}

public void setIpIdentifierId(int ipIdentifierId) {
    this.ipIdentifierId = ipIdentifierId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ip_id", referencedColumnName = "ip_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public FinalInvolvedParty getIpById() {
    return ipById;
}

public void setIpById(FinalInvolvedParty ipById) {
    this.ipById = ipById;
}
....
```

my data is persisted correctly but when I fetch my data Hibernate get into an infinite recursion

[image]

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you fetching data through JSON?

Comment: The mapping is incorrect, but what you're seeing is perfectly normal. You have a father. Your father has sons and you're one of them. And you have a father, and your father has sons and you're one of them. And you have a father, and your father has sons and you're one of them, etc. etc. Hibernate doesn't go into an infinite recursion. Your code probably has an infinite recursion if you're trying to serialize this by serializing every field of every object without taking cycles into account.

Comment: thank you my friend,you really help me